# Change elements of a numpy array based on a return value of a function to which those elements are passed to

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array of RGBA values that looks something like this:

```
# Not all elements are [0, 0, 0, 0]
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       ...,
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

I also have a function which returns one of 5 values that a certain RGBA value is closest to (green, red, orange, brown, white).

```
def closest_colour(requested_colour):
    min_colours = {}
    for key, name in webcolors.CSS3_HEX_TO_NAMES.items():
        if name in ['green', 'red', 'orange', 'brown', 'white']:
            r_c, g_c, b_c = webcolors.hex_to_rgb(key)
            rd = (r_c - requested_colour[0]) ** 2
            gd = (g_c - requested_colour[1]) ** 2
            bd = (b_c - requested_colour[2]) ** 2
            min_colours[(rd + gd + bd)] = name
    return min_colours[min(min_colours.keys())]
```

I'd like to apply this function to each element of my numpy array and change those elements. I tried doing it this way:

```
img_array[closest_colour(img_array) == 'green'] = (0, 255, 0, 1)
img_array[closest_colour(img_array) == 'red'] = (255, 0, 0, 1)
img_array[closest_colour(img_array) == 'brown'] = (92, 64, 51, 1)
img_array[closest_colour(img_array) == 'orange'] = (255, 165, 0, 1)
img_array[closest_colour(img_array) == 'white'] = (255, 255, 255, 0)
```

but I get an error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

I am aware of why this error occurs but I also don't know a different way to do this efficiently.

Is there a way to do this efficiently as I'm working with a fairly large array (image)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would rewrite your function to be a bit more vectorized. First, you really don't need to loop through the entire dictionary of CSS colors for every pixel: the lookup table can be trivially precomputed. Second, you can map the five colors you want to RGBA values without using the names as an intermediary. This will make your life much easier since you'll be working with numbers instead of strings most of the time.

```
names = dict.fromkeys(['green', 'red', 'orange', 'brown', 'white'])
for key, name in webcolors.CSS3_HEX_TO_NAMES.items():
    if name in names:
        names[name] = key
lookup = np.array([webcolors.hex_to_rgb(key) + (1,) for key in names.values()])
```

Since the number of colors is small, you can compute an Nx5 array of distances to the colors:

```
distance = ((rgba[..., None, :] - lookup)**2).sum(axis=-1)
```

If you don't want to include the transparency in the distance, remove it from the comparison:

```
distance = ((rgba[..., None, :3] - lookup[..., :3])**2).sum(axis=-1)
```

This gives you an Nx5 array of distances (where N can be more than one dimension, because of the intentional use of `...` instead of `:`). The minima are at

```
closest = distance.argmin(-1)
```

Now you can apply this index directly to the lookup table:

```
result = lookup[closest]
```

Here is a sample run:

```
>>> np.random.seed(42)
>>> rgba = np.random.randint(255, size=(10, 4))
>>> rgba
array([[102, 179,  92,  14],
       [106,  71, 188,  20],
       [102, 121, 210, 214],
       [ 74, 202,  87, 116],
       [ 99, 103, 151, 130],
       [149,  52,   1,  87],
       [235, 157,  37, 129],
       [191, 187,  20, 160],
       [203,  57,  21, 252],
       [235,  88,  48, 218]])
>>> lookup = np.array([
...     [0, 255, 0, 1],
...     [255, 0, 0, 1],
...     [92, 64, 51, 1],
...     [255, 165, 0, 1],
...     [255, 255, 255, 0]], dtype=np.uint8)

>>> distance = ((rgba[..., None, :3] - lookup[..., :3])**2).sum(axis=-1)
>>> distance
array([[ 24644,  63914,  15006,  32069,  55754],
       [ 80436,  62586,  19014,  66381,  60546],
       [ 72460,  82150,  28630,  69445,  43390],
       [ 15854,  81134,  20664,  41699,  63794],
       [ 55706,  57746,  11570,  50981,  58256],
       [ 63411,  13941,   5893,  24006, 116961],
       [ 66198,  26418,  29294,   1833,  57528],
       [ 41505,  39465,  25891,   4980,  63945],
       [ 80854,   6394,  13270,  14809,  96664],
       [ 85418,  10448,  21034,   8633,  71138]])
>>> closest = distance.argmin(-1)
>>> closest
array([2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 3])
>>> lookup[closest]
array([[ 92,  64,  51,   1],
       [ 92,  64,  51,   1],
       [ 92,  64,  51,   1],
       [  0, 255,   0,   1],
       [ 92,  64,  51,   1],
       [ 92,  64,  51,   1],
       [255, 165,   0,   1],
       [255, 165,   0,   1],
       [255,   0,   0,   1],
       [255, 165,   0,   1]], dtype=uint8)
```

Comment: I was also in the process of rewriting the OP's function, but you were faster.. and much better than what I have done so far :)

Comment: @VladimirFokow. Good call. Will fix momentarily

Comment: `webcolors.hex_to_rgb(hex_value)` returns 3 numbers, not 4

Comment: @VladimirFokow. I added an extra `+ (1,)`. OP is making their own table anyway in that case

Comment: but the distance now is not what OP is calculating

Comment: just add 3 here `rgba[..., None, :3]`

Comment: Wow, this is really amazing. I'm still fairly new to python so seeing something like this is an eye-opener. Thanks a lot! @MadPhysicist

Comment: Also, sorry to bother you but I mistakenly showed my array as a NxM array when it's actually an NxMxD array or rather in code ```array([[[0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0], ...]])```. Are there changes that need to be made to the code because of this?

Comment: @Jamess11. I don't think so, but let me know if you run into issues

Comment: @Jamess11 you can always change your selection

Comment: @MadPhysicist First, thanks for helping.  Main issue I'm having is that after I change the said array using your method I want to convert it back to an image. I do this using `PIL` library by using `Image.fromarray(lookup[closest])` and then subsequently saving it to a `.png` file. However, this always leaves me with a blank image file. I've changed my alpha values of colors to 255 as well but the result is the same. Do you have an idea as to why this might be happening or is it just related to PIL, since your method seems to be working correctly?

Comment: I'm going to guess that the wrong datatype is being used somewhere. `lookup` needs to be `np.uint8`, and you might need to tell PIL what type of image you have

Comment: @MadPhysicist Sorry, for some reason I didn't get notified of your comment. I've managed to make it work, although there seems to be some unexpected behavior regarding the "closeness" of colors. For example, it replaces `[0, 0, 0, 0]` with `[0, 128, 0, 255]` which shouldn't be happening. And when I replace the `:3` with `:4` in the `distance` line I get better results although still not as good as using two for loops.

Comment: @MadPhysicist The issue was integer overflow but I fixed it. Thanks once again.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Accepted as I think it's the best way, but unfortunately for some reason the approach doesn't work for green colors in my image so I ended up sticking to my approach. I have no clue why it doesn't work for green but it works for all other colors. Even more baffling is how it works in my approach even though both are using Euclidean distance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`numpy.apply_along_axis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html):

```py
np.apply_along_axis(closest_colour, axis=1, arr=img_array)
```

If you would just like to replace these values with new ones, let your function return these new values.

Comment: This is the right way to apply a function, but it's just a for loop under the hood. In addition, the function itself is terribly inefficient.